# Table of XML data using for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Hello everybody I am trying to use FOR loop in Javascript to fill a table from data given by an external XML file the Script is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



        var xmlDoc;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","data.xml",false);
            //xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;



        var x=0;

    document.write("<table border='1'>");

    for (var i=0;i<x.numstudents;i++)
      { 

      x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("students");
       var studentstr= "student_"+(i+1);
        stustr= x[i].getElementsByTagName(studentstr)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName(studentstr)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

      sum=0;
      for (var j=0;j<numtests;j++)
      {
      var mystr= "test_"+(j+1);
                    document.write("<tr><td>");
      tststr= x[i].getElementsByTagName(mystr)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName(mystr)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

    } 
      }
    document.write("</table>");

        </script>
```

The following code is the one of the student in XML code:

```
<CATALOG>
        <numstudents>10</numstudents>       
        <numtests>7</numtests>          
 <students>
 <student_1>
            <name> B    </name>
    <test_1>2   </test_1>
    <test_2>2   </test_2>
    <test_3>2   </test_3>
    <test_4>2   </test_4>
    <test_5>2   </test_5>
    <test_6>2   </test_6>
    <test_7>2   </test_7>

</student_1>
</students>

</CATALOG>
```

The problem I am facing is about the string and how to put it in the table. Can anybody suggest anyway to fix this problem.
note: I am trying to Learn JavaScript so please help and don't confuse me.

Comment: Make sure to use the Code buttons to format code correctly (`{}` on the toolbar), or ensure each line is spaced in 4 spaces from the left.

Comment: So ... is there a problem of some sort?

Comment: @Pointy The Problem is the way to display the data in a table and the strings I am using with the for loops

Comment: But specifically, what doesn't work; does it display nothing, the wrong thing, look wrong - what ?

Comment: Also, an example of the XML would help.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't really know why my code isn't working, I dont even know what to fix.

Comment: In that case, it might help if you explain *how* you know its not working...

Comment: @RussC It's simply not displaying anything when I run it.

Comment: I don't know if it's part of the problem, but you should never `document.write` incomplete elements, such as just the opening tag as in `document.write("<table>");` It's better to collect everything into one string and use `document.write` once at the end. Actually you shopuldn't be using `document.write` at all, but that's a different story and to long for a comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest you try the following to debug your code:

1) Check that the XML doc is actually loaded into the variable `xmlDoc`. Do an `alert(xmlDoc)` or `console.log(xmlDoc)`. It's initialization is not shown in your given code.

2) Secondly, check that you have closed all brackets. In your code, line 8, the document.write() is not closed properly. Simple errors like these will cause the entire script to break. To view more errors, try using the browser console (in Chrome it's **CTRL-SHIFT-J**, FF & IE is **F12**)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I only posted the part that has with the for loop and getting elements from the XML then posting them in the table, I already have in my code console.log(xmlDoc) and I used your advice to check for all errors in the script and right now it dosn't have any but still not working. Any suggestions??